# How to read byte array into FileStream

Tags: c#

I have an byte array and I want to read the byte array into a FileStream. Below is my sample of code:

```
string fileName = "test.txt";
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
FileStream fs = new FileStream();
fs.ReadByte(file);
object obj = LoadFile<object>(fs);

public static T LoadFile<T>(FileStream fs)
{
    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)bf.Deserialize(gzip);
    }
}
```

In the method above, I have use FileStream to read byte array, but unlucky fs.ReadByte cannot read byte array. Any help please focus on how to Read byte array into a FileStream for using as a parameter in method "LoadFile". Please do not read directly the file into FileStream because the file here is loaded from somewhere else like from database or other source.

Comment: Why don't you use a MemoryStream instead of the FileStream?

Comment: MemoryStream can use as FileStream on the method LoadFile?

Comment: How is your code compiling `FileStream` does not take 0 arguments in the constuctor

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
string fileName = "test.txt";
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
memStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
```

Comment: Your method is using memStream but I got an error from your code. It said this: "The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 1F-8B-08-00-00-00-00-00-04-00-ED-BD-07-60-1C-49-96" when run at line Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);

Comment: Currently, I am using this code to get the file:

`byte[] file;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

                    }

                }`

Comment: If your file is zipped, which I assume it is because of the use of a `GZipStream`, then that is likely why this isn't working.

Comment: I have analyze my code and come to a conclusion as your thought. So I have post my new code above to require more help. If it is in your case, please help me with that.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure where the misunderstanding is. FileStream represents a file on disk. You cannot "read bytes into it" without writing them to disk and you cannot read from it without reading from disk.

Maybe what you want is a MemoryStream which can contain arbitrary contents.

Both derive from Stream.

Comment: Yes. I have said that FileStream cannot read byte directly. If MemoryStream can contain Byte Array, then how can I use it for my method "LoadFile"?

Comment: Either change `LoadFile` to take a `Stream` or write your `byte` array to a file and create a `FileStream` from that.

Comment: Use the fact that both derive from Stream so you can pass *any* stream. You are about to experience the usefulness of inheritance :)

Comment: If I write byte array to a file, and then read the file back to FileStream, then how can I Read a file if it is exist only on database but not on any drive on server?

Comment: If you don't want to write the byte array to a file to read it, and really that was the worse of my two options.  Then all you have to do is change `LoadFile` to take a `Stream` instead of a `FileStream` then load the byte array in a `MemoryStream` and pass that.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing in my code now. Using MemoryStream to write byte array into it and then pass it to an object. But currently I am got a stuck at passing the MemoryStream. It look like the byte array doesn't have an correct format.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah! Now I got a good solution after doing some more research. As the topic I have posted "How to read byte array into FileStream". We cannot read byte array into FileStream, it just use to read a file on driver to byte array. So I have change a little bit on my code, and now I have a file to read it using FileStream. How I made a file?

In this context I have an object. The object is anything as you want!

I use a collection as a samble object.

```
Collection<object> list = new Collection<object>();
//Now I will write this list to a file. fileName is what you want and be sure that folder Files is exist on server or at the root folder of your project
WriteFile(list, Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName));
//The method to write object to file is here
public static void WriteFile<T>(T obj, string path)
{
    FileStream serializeStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(serializeStream, obj);
    serializeStream.Flush();
    serializeStream.Close();
}
```

After I have wrote my object to a file, I need a method to read it back to object. So I do write this method:

```
public static Collection<object> ReatFile(string fileName){
            //I have to read the file which I have wrote to an byte array            
            byte[] file;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                {
                    file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

                }

            }
            //And now is what I have to do with the byte array of file is to convert it back to object which I have wrote it into a file
            //I am using MemoryStream to convert byte array back to the original object.
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            memStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
            Collection<object> list = (Collection<object>)obj;
            return list;
}
```

After doing some steps above, I am now can write any type object to file and then read it back to original object. Thank too much for any help I have got there.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you run `File.ReadAllBytes` prior to the usage of your `FileStream`?

```
string fileName = "test.txt";
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    object obj = LoadFile<object>(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: In my question, I have mentioned that the byte array is not reading from any file on server. It is just an byte array I got from database or other source. So please do not read file directly into FileStream.

Comment: Why `So please do not read file directly into FileStream`? You're using `Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName)` to read the file on disk. Don't use FileStream on that if you don't intend to read any files on disk.

Comment: You right. I only have byte array and it isn't loaded from any file. So can you help me with this? Because the method "LoadFile" require a FileStream, and I just have a byte array from database. So how can I use it for my method "LoadFile"?